# Accounting for lackluster AI in Raid Battles

Tags: dragalia-lost

I've been farming the Expert Raid Battles in the most recent [event](https://dragalialost.gamepress.gg/resplendent-refrain-event-guide) in Dragalia Lost. It isn't uncommon for 1-2 members of my team to be down within the first minute of the battle simply because they didn't move out of the way when [Sabnock](https://dragalialost.gamepress.gg/resplendent-refrain-event-guide) casts Dark Side.

This is an issue I encountered in the previous Raid Event as well but wasn't quite as frustrated by due to my team's might barely being above the minimum requirement (7800+). My team's might is currently just above 11,0000 (well above the minimum requirement), but I'm still having issues with keeping them alive. It's preventing me from completing all of the Quest Endeavors and simply makes it more difficult to defeat Sabnock.

I haven't been able to find anything in the way of solutions on the internet, just people acknowledging how companion AI is something that could stand to be improved (e.g., [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/DragaliaLost/comments/9ox6nc/is_it_just_me_or_is_the_ai_particularly_bad_on/)).

Are there any steps I can take to improve my companions' chances of surviving the fight, or am I pretty much at the mercy of the developers on this issue?